# JavaScript Arrays .push() not working as Expected

Tags: javascript

I'm writing this JavaScript code expecting the output as

[["o","o","x","o","o"],["o","x","x","x","o"]]

but instead it gives

[image: Received output in the console]

```
<script>
function createArray(x) {
  var array=[];
  var finalArray=[];
  
  for(var i=1;i<=x;i++){
    array[i-1]='O';
  }

  var midIndex=Math.round(x/2)-1;
  
  array[midIndex]='X';


  finalArray.push(array);

  var num1=midIndex-1;
  var num2=midIndex+1;
 
 
  
    array[num1]="X";
    array[num2]="X";
    
    finalArray.push(array);

  console.log(finalArray) ;
  
}

createArray(5);


</script>
```

please some one show the reason for this.

Comment: Try `finalArray.push(array.slice());` the first time.

Comment: `.push()` doesn't clone the array you're pushing into `finalArray`. You push the "same array" (a reference to the same array) twice.

Comment: [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because **Javascript** objects are passed by **reference**. You should create a copy of the array and push to the final one

```js
function createArray(x) {
  var arr=[];
  var finalArray=[];
  
  for(var i=1;i<=x;i++){
    arr[i-1]='O';
  }

  var midIndex=Math.round(x/2)-1;
  
  arr[midIndex]='X';


  finalArray.push(arr.slice());

  var num1=midIndex-1;
  var num2=midIndex+1;
 
 
  
    arr[num1]="X";
    arr[num2]="X";
    
    finalArray.push(arr.slice());

  console.log(finalArray) ;
  
}

createArray(5);
```

Answer (score 3):

In Javascript, objects(in your case **array**) are passed by **reference**. You push the `array` into `finalArray` and then update the array. But you have updated the data from same reference. So you could use **spread operator** which would effectively create a new array(with new reference) and you can push this array to `finalArray`

```
finalArray.push([...array]);
```

Comment: This is called [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) not destructuring

Comment: @adiga Was just about to comment the same. Spot ON

Answer (score 2):

It's for JS pointer When you Push array into final u push pointer of array into an index of final and when change array the final changed too.

for resolve it u can use easy Code:

```
finalArray.push([...array]);
```

GoodLuck